# How to implement sorter and filter in NG-ZORRO (Ant design) table

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I am using `ng-zorro-antd` table in my application. I am unable to implement filter and sorter as table columns and the table data is dynamic.

Please see my current code below:

```html
<nz-table
  #rowSelectionTable
  [nzData]="data"
  [nzPageSize]="20"
  (nzCurrentPageDataChange)="currentPageDataChange($event)"
  (nzPageIndexChange)="refreshStatus($event)"
  (nzPageSizeChange)="refreshStatus($event)"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th
        nzShowSort
        nzShowFilter
        [nzFilters]="tradeCodeList"
        (nzFilterChange)="search($event,searchAddressList)"
        *ngFor="let col of transDataCols; let i = index"
      >
        {{col}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of rowSelectionTable.data">
      <td *ngFor="let item of transDataCols">{{data[item]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

What should I do to allow sorting/filtering for all the columns?

Comment: Hi Santhosh, did you check their documentation? [Here](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-head) they show it very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the following properties on the `th` element:

```html
<th
  nzShowSort
  nzSortKey="{{col}}"
  nzShowFilter
>
</th>
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful.I was looking at the doc and when I put [nzSortFn]="true" instead of  nzShowFilter it shows an error. I almost wasted 30 min looking for the source of the problem.